# How to set up a 'what if' parameter that affects objects from R script

Tags: r, powerbi, powerquery

I have an R script in which I train and simulate an ARIMA algorithm to predict a series of prices; said predictions are then stored as objects. When I insert that script into Power Query (Power BI) I am able to extract said objects in order to plot them.

Now I want to insert a friendly user 'What if' parameter in my Power BI dashboard that can change my prices series to see how those predictions change in turn; but, since the algorithm and simulation are defined by the objects created in the R script, my forecast will not be altered.

I've tried looking for ways to previously upload my prices df in PowerBI and then call it up at the beginning of my R script; but so far, no success. I can't seem to use the loaded csv in my script without it returning this error when runnning it: "ErrorCode=-2147467259 ExceptionType=Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.R.Exceptions.RScriptRuntimeException"

Comment: hi Guille! Surely you could save it as a csv and then read it in using Power BI?

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the obvious solution; but for whatever reason I can't seem to use the loaded csv in my script without it returning this error when runnning it, which is why I chose the other method in the first place: 

"ErrorCode=-2147467259
    ExceptionType=Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.R.Exceptions.RScriptRuntimeException"

Comment: Guille I'd add that to your question. I'm not familiar with Power BI, so I can't help you with the error, but it should attract someone who can